# iOS Google maps sdk method "idleAtCameraPosition" is not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

```
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView
idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
{}
```

The above mentioned method is not getting called even after the user gesture(pan) is stopped on the map.

How to make that work, when the user interaction is stopped in the map ?

Reference: [Google Maps Documentation for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p#af1129dee4fcef90292d96c0aa7764ced)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was new in the 1.4 release so make sure you are running that.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases#version_140_-_july_2013

Comment: Yep. Just noticed that, its introduced only in the new version(1.4) SDK! Thanks.